# Italic font for the entire verbatim section

Tags: fonts, formatting, verbatim, italic

How can I change the font format to italic within the verbatim environment ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}
@book{book;
title = {title};
author = {author};
volume = {1};
year = {2015};
publisher = {x}
}
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide complete code. `Verbatim` is not a standard environment.

Comment: @cfr: `fancyvrb` package

Comment: I want present the snipped of code in the document as a text, something like this 
\begin{Verbatim}
@book{book;
title = {title};
author = {author};
volume = {1};
year = {2015};
publisher = {x}
}
\end{Verbatim}

Comment: @ChristianHupfer OK. But the OP should include that in the question. Especially since the question conflates `verbatim` and `Verbatim`. The former *is*, of course, a default environment.

Comment: @Michal You should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @cfr: I did not contradict you...

Comment: Your example code is ambiguous; you are using `Verbatim`, which requires the `fancyvrb` package; otherwise, it should be `verbatim`. In any case, my answer gives both options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Locally,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}[fontshape=it]
@book{book,
title = {title},
author = {author},
volume = {1},
year = {2015},
publisher = {x}
}
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Globally,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\fvset{fontshape=it}

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}
@book{book,
title = {title},
author = {author},
volume = {1},
year = {2015},
publisher = {x}
}
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

This will give italic mono-spaced font:

[image]

For the standard `verbatim` environment, redefine `\verbatim@font`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\verbatim@font{\itshape}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
@book{book,
title = {title},
author = {author},
volume = {1},
year = {2015},
publisher = {x}
}
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the `verbatimbox` package that allows formatting macros to be supplied in an optional argument.  It has the `verbnobox` environment, that functions in a manner similar to `verbatim`, and the `verbbox` environment that places the verbatim content into a saved box, which can later be output, inline, with `theverbbox`, shown here inside an `\fbox`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox} 
\begin{document}

\noindent Normal Size, italic shape verbatim text
\begin{verbnobox}[\itshape]
@book{book;
title = {title};
author = {author};
volume = {1};
year = {2015};
publisher = {x}
}
\end{verbnobox}

\begin{verbbox}[\itshape\tiny]
@book{book;
title = {title};
author = {author};
volume = {1};
year = {2015};
publisher = {x}
}
\end{verbbox}
Here is \fbox{\theverbbox} inline.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The optional argument of the `verbatimbox` macros is really quite programmable.  Here, the "program" is stored in `\tmp`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox} 
\begin{document}
\def\tmp{\ifnum\theVerbboxLineNo=2\itshape\else%
         \ifnum\theVerbboxLineNo=4\leavevmode\llap{$\bullet$ }\fi\fi}
\begin{verbnobox}[\tmp]
@book{book;
title = {title};
author = {author};
volume = {1};
year = {2015};
publisher = {x}
}
\end{verbnobox}
\end{document}
```

[image]